# Why does Airflow create multiple log files?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have recently started working on Airflow scheduler. And I have been observing that it is creating multiple log files for each job that is scheduled. May I know how to restrict it to just one file. I have checked airflow.cfg file and I weren't able to find any argument which is related to the number of copies of log files.